# does jquery parse XML documents and JS ARRAYS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing, jquery-selectors

I was trying to figure out if it was possible to pass in a js array as the selector and then program with it.

Similarly, I wanted to know if i got the return from a function (in the format of a XML doc) and put it into the jQuery selector, would i be able to parse it.

Comment: Would it have killed to try it :)

Comment: dont have means at the moment...  It was a spurr of the moment thought.

Comment: ctrl+shift+j in google chrome on this page and then `$([1,2,3]).each(function(){
    console.log(this);
});` for example

Comment: An array containing **what**? jQuery will handle an array of DOM elements passed as input to the `jQuery()/$()` function. It should also handle XML, provided it's well-formatted.

Comment: it is an array of divs.   essentailly  something to the lines of:
SELECTED.push($(tar).closest(".draggable"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it out, and as long as the JS array is of HTML Elements (In my case, Divs) then it worked just fine.  The difference was slightly different when it came to referencing.  Ex:

```
 $(SELECTED).closest(".draggable").css("background-color","pink");
```

now would become:

```
 $(SELECTED).each(function(){
   $(this).closest("draggable").css("background-color","pink");
 });
```